# SQL Server Max() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column named as `Quarter` in which data is as below:

```
Quarter
--------
Q3-2017
Q2-2017
Q1-2017
Q4-2016
Q3-2016
Q2-2016
Q1-2016
Q1-2018
```

I want to find `max()` from above. How should I proceed.

When I tried with `MAX()` function it is giving me output as `Q4-2017`.

Comment: what is your current query? what output are you expecting?

Comment: If you put the year first you would not have this problem, i.e. format the data like "2017-Q4"

Comment: you better to add a date column and find Max of that column

Comment: i want the result to be return as Q1-2018.

Comment: Ugly way to do it could be `select MAX(Quarter) over (order by right(Quarter,4), RIGHT(LEFT(Quarter, 2), 1)) from YourTable` ... which will first order by year, then quarter number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because it's giving you the max of the column which is in a string format. It's ordering it Alpha-numerically and that's the max value when you sort the data. If you want to order it as you expect, you need to use some string manipulation to break the values down for ordering.

```
CREATE TABLE #quarters
    (
        [quarter] NVARCHAR(10)
    );

INSERT INTO #quarters ( quarter )
VALUES ( 'Q3-2017' ) ,
       ( 'Q2-2017' ) ,
       ( 'Q1-2017' ) ,
       ( 'Q4-2016' ) ,
       ( 'Q3-2016' ) ,
       ( 'Q2-2016' ) ,
       ( 'Q1-2016' ) ,
       ( 'Q1-2018' );

SELECT   q.quarter Original ,
         CAST(RIGHT(q.quarter, 4) AS INT) AS TheYear , -- extracts the year
         CAST(SUBSTRING(q.quarter, 2, 1) AS INT) AS TheQuarter -- extracts the quarter
FROM     #quarters AS q
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(q.quarter, 4) AS INT) DESC ,
         CAST(SUBSTRING(q.quarter, 2, 1) AS INT) DESC;

DROP TABLE #quarters;
```

Produces:

```
Original   TheYear     TheQuarter
---------- ----------- -----------
Q1-2018    2018        1
Q3-2017    2017        3
Q2-2017    2017        2
Q1-2017    2017        1
Q4-2016    2016        4
Q3-2016    2016        3
Q2-2016    2016        2
Q1-2016    2016        1
```

The above solution would also work without the casting: `CAST((XXX) AS INT)`, but it's safer to do that in case an unexpected value appears.

And to get the top value, use [`TOP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT TOP 1 q.quarter Original 
FROM     #quarters AS q
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(q.quarter, 4) AS INT) DESC ,
     CAST(SUBSTRING(q.quarter, 2, 1) AS INT) DESC;
```

Comment: yeah it is working fine now but can you please help me to get only one value out of this that is max i want result to be only Q1-2018

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like :
**SELECT  quarter from QuarterTable where right(quarter,4) = (select max(right(quarter,4) from QuarterTable);**

Answer (score 0):

Split `quarter` field into `year` (numeric!) and `quarter` (string), and `order by` at your taste.
Get first row (`top 1`) to get only the max value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 quarter, 
CAST(SUBSTRING(quarter, 4, 4) AS INTEGER) AS y,  
SUBSTRING(quarter, 1, 2) AS q FROM quarter
ORDER BY y desc, q desc
```